# Makefile for kgec (quantum espresso)

Tags: makefile

I am trying to use `make` on Windows for the KGEC post-processor to Quantum Espresso. I'd really appreciate if someone can help me out.

```
QEV=6.1
DQEV=QE6

TYPE=mpi
QE=F:/Software/qe-6.6

#===================================================================

ifneq (,$(findstring QE6, $(DQEV)))
  include $(QE)/make.inc
endif
ifneq (,$(findstring QE5, $(DQEV)))
  include $(QE)/make.sys
endif

F90FLAGS += -D__$(DQEV)
#F90FLAGS = -O0 -debug all  -check all  -traceback  -fpp -D__$(DQEV)
#-fpe3 #-ftrapuv #-fpe:0

export 

SRCDIR=./for-qe-$(QEV)-$(TYPE)

#===================================================================

all :
    (cp -r ./src $(SRCDIR); cp makefiles/Makefile.for-qe-$(QEV) $(SRCDIR); \
         cd $(SRCDIR); pwd; $(MAKE) -f Makefile.for-qe-$(QEV) kgec.x || exit 1)

clean :
    rm -fr $(SRCDIR)
```

I've never used `make` before but I think I pretty much understand what it's supposed to do (copy the folder `src` and the correct makefile from the `makefile` folder to `SRCDIR`; and then execute rule `kgec.x` from that file). However powershell is returning the following error:

```
PS F:\Software\kgec-v2.1> make
(cp -r ./src ./for-qe-6.1-mpi; cp makefiles/Makefile.for-qe-6.1 ./for-qe-6.1-mpi; \
         cd ./for-qe-6.1-mpi; pwd; C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/make/tools/install/bin/make.exe -f Makefile.for-qe-6.1 kgec.x || exit 1)
cp: target `kgec.x' is not a directory
make: *** [Makefile:66: all] Error 1
```

I'm not sure where this `cp` error is coming from because the version file (below) has no `cp` command at all. For completeness' sake, here is the version file:

```
#
# Makefile for kgec (( K)ubo-(G)reenwood (E)lectrical (C)onductivity )
# By Lazaro Calderin
# Oct, 2016
#

MODULESM = -I $(QE)/Modules -I $(QE)/PW/src -I ../src
PPOBJS = $(QE)/PP/src/openfil_pp.o
PWOBJS = $(QE)/PW/src/libpw.a
QEOBJS = $(QE)/Modules/libqemod.a $(QE)/FFTXlib/libqefft.a $(QE)/LAXlib/libqela.a
MODULES = $(MODULESM) $(PWOBJS) $(QEOBJS)
LIBOBJS = $(QE)/clib/clib.a $(QE)/iotk/src/libiotk.a

#================================================================
all : kgec.x

kgecout.o : kgecout.f90
    $(MPIF90) $(F90FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ $(MODULES) -warn all

kgecgradient.o : kgecpaw.mod apawgm.mod qe_p_psi.mod kgecgradient.f90
    $(MPIF90) $(F90FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ $(MODULES) -warn all

kgecpaw.o : kgecpaw.f90
    $(MPIF90) $(F90FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ $(MODULES) -warn all

kgecchecks.o : kgecpaw.mod kgecchecks.f90
    $(MPIF90) $(F90FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ $(MODULES) -warn all

parallel.o : parallel.f90
    $(MPIF90) $(F90FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ $(MODULES) -warn all

kgecvars.o : kgecvars.f90
    $(MPIF90) $(F90FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ $(MODULES) -warn all

kgsigma1.o : kgecvars.mod kgsigma1.f90
    $(MPIF90) $(F90FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ $(MODULES) -warn all

kgsigma2.o : kgecvars.mod kgsigma2.f90
    $(MPIF90) $(F90FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ $(MODULES) -warn all

qevars.o: qevars.f90
    $(MPIF90) $(F90FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ $(MODULES) -warn all

apawgm.o: apawgm.f90
    $(MPIF90) $(F90FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ $(MODULES) -warn all

kgec.o: qevars.mod qe_p_psi.mod apawgm.mod kgecvars.mod kgsigma1.mod \
        kgsigma2.mod parallel.mod kgecchecks.mod kgecpaw.mod \
        kgecgradient.mod kgecout.mod kgec.f90
    $(MPIF90) $(F90FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ $(MODULES) -warn all

kgecout.mod : kgecout.f90 kgecout.o

kgecgradient.mod : kgecgradient.f90 kgecgradient.o
    @true

kgecpaw.mod : kgecpaw.f90 kgecpaw.o
    @true

kgecchecks.mod : kgecchecks.f90 kgecchecks.o
    @true

parallel.mod : parallel.f90 parallel.o
    @true

kgecvars.mod : kgecvars.f90 kgecvars.o
    @true

kgsigma1.mod : kgsigma1.f90 kgsigma1.o
    @true

kgsigma2.mod : kgsigma2.f90 kgsigma2.o
    @true

qevars.mod : qevars.f90 qevars.o
    @true

apawgm.mod : apawgm.f90 apawgm.o
    @true
    
qe_p_psi.o : qe_p_psi.f90
    $(MPIF90) $(F90FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ $(MODULES) -warn all
    
qe_p_psi.mod : qe_p_psi.f90 qe_p_psi.o
    @true

kgec.x : kgec.o qevars.o apawgm.o qe_p_psi.o kgecvars.o kgsigma1.o \
         kgsigma2.o parallel.o kgecchecks.o kgecpaw.o kgecgradient.o \
         kgecout.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(MODULES) \
    $(PPOBJS) $(QELIBS) $(LIBOBJS) $(LIBS)
    (cd ../)

clean :
    - /bin/rm -f *.x *.o *~ *.F90 *.d *.mod *.i work.pc
```

Comment: This makefile is written for a POSIX system like GNU/Linux or MacOS, with a POSIX shell and POSIX utilities like `cp`, `rm`, etc.  You are trying to run it on Windows, which is not a POSIX system and doesn't have those things.  Also note that just because you invoke `make` from PowerShell, definitely does **not** mean that it will use PowerShell to run the recipe commands... it would be a nightmare if make always used whatever shell the user happened to be running.  On POSIX systems it always uses `/bin/sh`.  On Windows it depends how `make` was built but usually it uses `cmd.exe`.

Comment: @MadScientist: I should clarify that I used chocolatey to install `make` on windows and `coreutils` for windows to run `cp` etc.

Comment: Just installing doesn't mean that `make` will use these things.  You need to ensure that (a) the directory containing these tools is on your `PATH`, before any other directory that contains similar tools that work differently, and (b) that you set make to use the right shell (this makefile requires a POSIX shell, as I mentioned above).  Just installing a few packages is not sufficient to take a build system expecting a POSIX setup and run it on Windows.  You'll have to learn a lot about the differences and understand how to modify them.

Comment: Well I did do the first. Also the windows PowerShell successfully executed several of these commands when fed via the prompt.

Comment: As I said in my first comment, make doesn't invoke PowerShell (by default).  It invokes `cmd.exe` (probably, depending on how it was compiled).  But the command line in the makefile cannot be run in PowerShell.  It must be run in a POSIX shell (`sh` or a variant such as `bash`).